# ASP .NET Core Layouts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently i'm writing asp.net core mvc app and i scaffolded the default identity . The problem is - On my home view i redirect to scaffolded login page when "Login " button is clicked, but layout on login page didn't load.
Is it possible to load the same layout in scaffolded login page ?
My home page - https://pasteboard.co/IfBZ8em.png
My Login page - https://pasteboard.co/IfC0gVj.png
Only my index view shows the layout

Comment: Please list what exactly you scaffolded! I "scaffolded the default identity" is very ambiguous.

Comment: I overwrite all files from identity scaffold

Comment: What's in "Areas/Identity/Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml"?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you don't have`@{Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}` in your `ViewStart.cshtml` file. This is located in
**identity Folder** > **Pages** > **ViewStart.cshtml**. Add this and it should work

Comment: @ItsoDimitrov  then check your _Layout.cshtml for proper reference of your css and script files

Comment: Rebuild your Entire Solution and try it on a different browser

Comment: Well same problem